# Convert Char field to DateTime but only when the field contains a date of format dd/mm/yyyy - Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, datetime

I have a table:

`Comments (Id int identity primary key, PersonId Int(6), Comment1 Char(60))`

The field `Comment1` is supposed to contain nonessential comments **only**, however the field has been used to store nonessential comments but also important dates in the format dd/mm/yyyy.

So for example, the data in the table appears like the following:

```
* Id * PersonId *    Comment1     *
|  1 |        5 | Likes Chocolate |
|  2 |        5 | 19/05/1992      |
|  3 |        5 | 23/07/1999      |
|  4 |        5 | 05/06/1994      |
|  5 |        8 | 07/12/1998      |
|  6 |        8 | Is very Tall    |
|  7 |        8 | 24/05/1995      |
|  8 |        8 | 16/10/2002      |
|  9 |       11 | 13/11/2005      |
| 10 |       11 | 21/09/2000      |
| 11 |       11 | 8/99/100/23-1   |
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b621/4)

They now need to find the one row for each person which contains the most recent date in the `Comment1` field.

Firstly I tried to remove those rows which did not contain a valid date using the following Query:

```
Select 
  Id,
  PersonId,
  Case 
    When IsDate(Comment1) = 1 
    Then convert(date, cast(rtrim(Comment1) as nvarchar), 103)
    Else NULL
  End
From Comments
```

But this only returned me:

```
* Id * PersonId *    Comment1     *
|  4 |        5 | 1994-06-05      |
|  5 |        8 | 1998-12-07      |
```

The other rows being `(null)`. This can be seen in the SQL Fiddle link.

Could some one please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Once this select statement returns what I require I expect I should be able to return the most recent date per `PersonId` using an aggregate function.

Comment: FYI, you don't need the `Else NULL` in your case expression - anything that isn't handled in one of your cases will return null anyway.

Comment: There's no guarantee that it won't attempt the `CAST()` even if `ISDATE()` returns 0 - it can rearrange operations. So you need to split this into two queries (a filter step and a comparison step) with a temp table or variable between the two. Also use `CONVERT()` so that you can pass an appropriate format value.

Comment: The return value of ISDATE depends on the settings set by SET DATEFORMAT, SET LANGUAGE and Configure the default language Server Configuration Option.

Comment: @Bridge Thanks for that, I wasn't 100% sure it would.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'll keep this in mind, I'll probably go the temp table route. With regards using `Convert()` instead of `Cast()`, I can undrstand this with regards to dates, money values etc. But what format value would I require when casting a `Char` to a `nVarChar`? Thanks

Comment: I'd somehow missed the outer `convert` was already using a format, and only saw the inner `cast`. Now I'm struggling to understand why that inner `CAST` is in there at all.

Comment: I'm also looking to amend the table structure so that the `Comment1` field is of the data type `nVarChar` rather than `Char(60)`, `cast(rtrim(Comment1) as nvarchar)` originated from that chain of thought. But as you rightly said, is not required in this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [SET DATEFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx)

```
set dateformat dmy

Select 
  Id,
  PersonId,
  Case 
    When IsDate(Comment1) = 1 
    Then convert(date, cast(rtrim(Comment1) as nvarchar), 103)
    Else NULL 
  End
From Comments
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b621/5)